# wp_send_json doesn't work after do_action on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, request

I need to interact with a third party plugin to send SMS. The plugin is Bookly, which is for making appointments. I edited the Ajax.php that Bookly uses for saving the appointment. I've sent the SMS succesfully on Ajax.php. However, I want to code an external plugin to make the process controllable on admin panel.
I use a custom hook named "bookly_appointment_saved" and send an array with that. And in my new plugin I catch the hook succesfully. The SMS is always sent but the Ajax.php of Bookly doesn't send the response to the frontend. It keeps showing the page as loading.

Please see the codes below and help.

Ajax.php (Bookly) - Only related method is included.

```
/**
 * Save cart appointments.
 */
public static function saveAppointment()
{
    $userData = new Lib\UserBookingData( self::parameter( 'form_id' ) );

    if ( $userData->load() ) {
        $failed_cart_key = $userData->cart->getFailedKey();
        if ( $failed_cart_key === null ) {
            $cart_info = $userData->cart->getInfo();
            $is_payment_disabled = Lib\Config::paymentStepDisabled();
            $skip_payment = BookingProxy\CustomerGroups::getSkipPayment( $userData->getCustomer() );
            $gateways = self::getGateways( $userData, clone $cart_info );

            if ( $is_payment_disabled || isset( $gateways['local'] ) || $cart_info->getPayNow() <= 0 || $skip_payment ) {
                // Handle coupon.
                $coupon = $userData->getCoupon();
                if ( $coupon ) {
                    $coupon->claim()->save();
                }
                // Handle payment.
                $payment = null;
                if ( ! $is_payment_disabled && ! $skip_payment ) {
                    if ( $cart_info->getTotal() <= 0 ) {
                        if ( $cart_info->withDiscount() ) {
                            $payment = new Lib\Entities\Payment();
                            $payment
                                ->setType( Lib\Entities\Payment::TYPE_FREE )
                                ->setStatus( Lib\Entities\Payment::STATUS_COMPLETED )
                                ->setPaidType( Lib\Entities\Payment::PAY_IN_FULL )
                                ->setTotal( 0 )
                                ->setPaid( 0 )
                                ->save();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $payment = new Lib\Entities\Payment();
                        $status = Lib\Entities\Payment::STATUS_PENDING;
                        $type = Lib\Entities\Payment::TYPE_LOCAL;
                        $paid = 0;
                        foreach ( $gateways as $gateway => $data ) {
                            if ( $data['pay'] == 0 ) {
                                $status = Lib\Entities\Payment::STATUS_COMPLETED;
                                $type = Lib\Entities\Payment::TYPE_FREE;
                                $cart_info->setGateway( $gateway );
                                $payment->setGatewayPriceCorrection( $cart_info->getPriceCorrection() );
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ( $status !== Lib\Entities\Payment::STATUS_COMPLETED ) {
                            $gift_card = $userData->getGiftCard();
                            if ( $gift_card ) {
                                $type = Lib\Entities\Payment::TYPE_CLOUD_GIFT;
                                $cart_info->setGateway( $type );
                                if ( $gift_card->getBalance() >= $cart_info->getPayNow() ) {
                                    $status = Lib\Entities\Payment::STATUS_COMPLETED;
                                    $paid = $cart_info->getPayNow();
                                    $gift_card->charge( $paid )->save();
                                    $payment->setGatewayPriceCorrection( $cart_info->getPriceCorrection() );
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $payment
                            ->setType( $type )
                            ->setStatus( $status )
                            ->setPaidType( Lib\Entities\Payment::PAY_IN_FULL )
                            ->setTotal( $cart_info->getTotal() )
                            ->setTax( $cart_info->getTotalTax() )
                            ->setPaid( $paid )
                            ->save();
                    }
                }
                // Save cart.
                $order = $userData->save( $payment );
                if ( $payment !== null ) {
                    $payment->setDetailsFromOrder( $order, $cart_info )->save();
                }
                // Send notifications.
                Lib\Notifications\Cart\Sender::send( $order );
                $response = array(
                    'success' => true,
                );
            } else {
                $response = array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'error' => Errors::PAY_LOCALLY_NOT_AVAILABLE,
                );
            }
        } else {
            $response = array(
                'success' => false,
                'failed_cart_key' => $failed_cart_key,
                'error' => Errors::CART_ITEM_NOT_AVAILABLE,
            );
        }

        //Custom hook
        $user_appointed=$userData->getData();
        do_action('bookly_appointment_saved',
            $appointment=[
                'date'=>date("d/m/Y", strtotime($user_appointed['slots'][0][2]) ),
                'time'=>date("H:i", strtotime($user_appointed['slots'][0][2]) ),
                'full_name'=>$user_appointed['full_name']=''?$user_appointed['first_name'].' '.$user_appointed['last_name']:$user_appointed['full_name'],
                'service_name'=>$userData->cart->getItemsTitle(),

            ]
        );
        // end of hook


        $userData->sessionSave();
        wp_send_json( $response );
        
    }

    Errors::sendSessionError();
}
```

custom-sms-sender-plugin.php (My plugin)

```
 add_action('bookly_appointment_saved','send_sms');
function send_sms($appointment){
    
    $phone = "66666666666";
    $message="New appointment - ".$appointment['full_name']." Service: ".$appointment['service_name']." Date: ".$appointment['date']." Time:".$appointment['time'];
    $message = urlencode($message);


    $url= "//request url with parameters";

                    
    $request = wp_remote_get($url);
    if ($request['body'] !=30 || $request['body'] !=20 || $request['body'] !=40 || $request['body'] !=50 || $request['body'] != 51 || $request['body'] != 70 || $request['body'] != 85) {
        write_log("SENT - SMS Code : ".explode(" ",$request['body'])[1]);
    } else {
        write_log("ERROR - Code : ".$request['body']);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you first of all checked what is actually received on the frontend? Go and inspect the request using your browser dev tools, and check if the status code is okay, and what the response body actually contained.

Comment: By default it returns a response with an "html" element. But if there is the "do_action" line, it returns 0. That is the main problem.

Comment: Have you enabled wb debug mode, have you checked the error log? _"it returns 0."_ - as the actual _body_ content of the response?

Comment: The network tab of your browser's dev tools is your new best friend. Seriously. Look at it.

Comment: @O.Jones 0 is the response from the Network tab.

Comment: @CBroe No errors.

Comment: What happens when you make your `send_sms` function "do nothing", do you then get the JSON response as expected again? The `$appointment=` part in your do_action call shouldn't be there. I don't think it hurts, but it does not save any actual purpose either.

Comment: @CBroe actually inspecting the code deeper helped. The "write_log" lines caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It is caused by the "write_log" commands as the command doesn't exist. After changing the log method, it worked like a charm. Thanks for all comments.